# What does "--" and "-" mean on any Unix Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, parameters

can someone tell me whats the difference between `-` and `--`. For example, in this command:

```
 docker run --name some-name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password mysql
```

I understand that I am running a docker container with mysql as image, with the name some-name and the password some_password. What I do not get is why I use `--` for the name parameter and `-` for the password parameter.

Comment: See [getopt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt). Not all programs use double dash for long options though, for instance all options to [tag:ffmpeg] start with a single dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), options are letters preceded by a single dash. They can be combined; e.g. `ls -l -a` is equivalent to `ls -la`.

By [GNU convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html), long options are preceded by two dashes. Obviously, you can't combine them like normal options, but they are more readable.

Most options will have both forms; for example, most programs recognise `-h` and `--help` as equivalents.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thanks for the clear and quick answer, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This is an arbitrary convention and not all programs follow it, but usually - precedes a single-letter argument and -- precedes a full-or-multiple-word argument.

Answer (score 1):

> What does “--” and “-” mean on any Unix Shell?

`--` and `-` have no meaning in the shell.

These are simply parameters for the `docker` command.

If you want to know what meaning they have for the `docker` command, you will have to look them up in `man docker`.

There is absolutely no difference between `--name`, `-e`, `foo`, or `--!--!--!--`. They are all simply parameter names, the `-` is simply as much part of the name as the `n` or the `e`.

`--name` is the name of a parameter, `-e` is the name of a parameter, `run` is the name of a parameter.

> What I do not get is why I use `--` for the name parameter and `-` for the password parameter.

The short answer is: because that's what the author of the `docker` command chose to call those parameters.

The slightly longer answer is that there are some conventions that some commands follow to some degree. On particular, `docker` seems to follow these three very common conventions:

- "*subcommand*": this is a convention that was popularized by tools like `iproute2` and `git`, which have a single "master" command whose first parameter is the name of a "subcommand" (which then can have even more subcommands), for example: `ip route`, `ip addr add`, `git commit`, `git status`, `docker run`.
- "*short options*": this convention is as old as Unix, maybe even older. An option should be a single alphanumeric character preceded by a `-`. Multiple consecutive options can be combined. Examples: `mkdir -p`, `ls -la`.
- "*long options*": this convention comes from the GNU system. Options are whole descriptive words preceded by `--`. Example: `ls --color`

But I'd like to repeat, because it is very important to understand: this has nothing to do with the shell. These options are processed by `docker` and `docker` alone. The options would be exactly the same if you called `docker` from the Windows command line or from Python: no Unix shell in sight anywhere.